# mod_rewrite, put WordPress in sub-dir on server seamlessly?

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use WordPress for personal a blog. Now I want to make it my personal website. Hence, I'd like the URL to be `mysite.com` rather than `mysite.com/blog` (e.g. `mysite.com/2009/10/blog-entry` rather than `mysite.com/blog/2009/10/blog-entry`)

A simple way is to move `/blog/*` to `/blog`. But this will make WordPress files mess up with existing files I stored in `/`

What I did was:
- Create `.htaccess` in `/`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Automatically send to blog when entering homepage (no requestfile supplied)
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ /blog/index.php [L]

# When inside blog, parse parse stuff
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

It solved the problem. HOWEVER:

- all the css and js and embed uploaded image DON'T work, as mod_rewrite would keep rewriting this.
- mysite.com/wp-admin doesn't work, since it will be rewritten as `mysite.com/blog/index.php?...=wp-admin`

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule !^blog(/|$) blog%{REQUEST_URI}
```